# How to upload an image to GridFS using gridfs-stream?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs-stream

I have the following code, in which I'm using GridFS-stream to upload an image to my mongodb database that's called "test".

```
    const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable');
    var GridFS = Grid("test", mongoose.mongo);
    app.use(formidableMiddleware({multiples:true}));
    // for a driver/user to new a product
    app.post('/api/newRequest', (req, res) => {
        const form = new IncomingForm();

        const images = req.files.image;

        var writestream = GridFS.createWriteStream({
            filename: images[0].name
        });
        writestream.on('close', function (file) {
            console.log("WRITESTREAM CLOSED");
        });
      });
```

Upon sending /api/getRequest from the client, I get the following error at line `var writestream...`:

```
[0] (node:15733) DeprecationWarning: GridStore is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Please use GridFSBucket instead
[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'readPreference' of undefined
```